# Phonegap fire custom events on iOS

Tags: ios, events, plugins, cordova

I'm Trying to fire a custom event in phonegap on iOS. Ok what I've done so far : 
I've created a custom plugin , I'm able to call my plugin from Javascript and all work properly. Basically the plugin show a ModalViewController presenting some native functionality 
such as recording and editing a video, once the user has finished I will upload the video to youtube. I would like to fire an event when the download is completed but at the moment I wasn't able to do this.
This is part of the code I use :
In my index.html I have this function triggered by a click on a button, (I'm not a Javascript developer) nativeFunction basically call my custom plugin.

```
function testCustomPlugin()
{
    MyClass.nativeFunction(
                           function(result) {
                           alert("Success : \r\n"+result);      
                           },
                           function(error) {
                           alert("Error : \r\n"+error);      
                           }
    );
    document.addEventListener("post_sent",onPostSent,false);
}
function onPostSent()
{
    alert("post  sent");
}
```

This is my MyClass.js :

```
var MyClass = {
   nativeFunction: function(types, success, fail) {
   return Cordova.exec(success, fail, "MyClass", "showInterface", types);
   }
}
```

Inside MyClass.m I have two methods : showInterface and sendNotification,

showInterface.m

```
- (void) showInterface:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options
{
    self.callbackID = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    // missing code
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(sendSuccessNotification:) 
                                             name:@"PostSentNotification" object:nil];
}  

-(void)sendSuccessNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   if (self.callbackID) {
    NSLog(@"%@",callbackID);
    NSLog(@"sendSuccessNotification");

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"testCallBack"
                                             forKey:@"returnValue"];
    CDVPluginResult *result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK 
                                            messageAsDictionary:dictionary
   [result setKeepCallbackAsBool:YES];
   [super writeJavascript:[result toSuccessCallbackString:self.callbackID]];
   }

}
```

I can see in my log that sendSuccessNotification is called but the event is not fired, I am sure that I do something wrong in the javascript but the problem is that I don't know what.
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, I guess you are using PhoneGap / Cordova 1.5.0, right?
I'm asking because a lot of code has been changed in version 1.6.0.

In my opinion the following line is incorrect:

```
self.callbackID = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
```

You can check this yourself by debugging the string value.
According to my information the following statement should be used to retrieve the correct callback id for your result object:

```
self.callbackID = [arguments pop];
```

Also, please make sure that you have registered your plugin in your Cordova.plist.
Hope this solves your issue.

Best,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

your js does look a little weird - I recommend following this tutorial (or just download the project and take it from there;-)

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-ios.html